Execessive White Space
I'm trying to create a very simple web page as part of a project, but when I view the page in a browser (Safari, Chrome & Firefox) there is additional white space to the right.
I've used a basic css reset:
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

Also set a max-width on the body element of 1220px
When I inspect the DOM the body element is sized correctly at 1220px but when inspecting the root html elment the size is larger.

Here's my html & css


* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
  margin     : 0;
  padding    : 0;
  border     : none;
  }
body {
  font-family      : Helvetica;
  font-size        : 22px;
  max-width        : 1220px;
  color            : seashell;
  background-color : black;
  opacity          : 0.9;
  text-align       : center;
  }
a {
  color : seashell;
  }
header {
  width           : 100%;
  height          : 69px;
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  align-items     : center;
  border-bottom   : 1px solid seashell;
  }
.logo {
  margin-left : 10px;
  display     : inline-flex;
  }
.logo img {
  height      : 50px;
  }
nav {
  display     : inline-flex;
  }
.top-links {
  list-style      : none;
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-evenly;
  width           : 350px;
  }
<!-- Header & Navbar -->
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="./images/img-tea-cozy-logo.webp" alt="tea cozy logo">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="top-links">
      <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>




I tried to run your code in firefox but saw no white space you described. Also the html element will take up all the space so that is expected. You can edit html tag in css as well to change it's width but there might be no reason as everything resides in the body. Edit: By white space you don't mean having the browser shrink in width right? You mean white as in color?

When I refer to white space I mean the additional space outside the body. In the avove image my body is 1220px but when I maximise the browser the view port is 1920px, with the body left aligned. I would like to set the maximum viewport to the same as the body. Apologies if I caused confusion when discussing white space.

Try changing the margin under body to "margin: 0 auto;"
If that doesn't work try adding this property too:
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

If that doesn't work try doing this instead:
html {
  margin: 0;
}

Setting max-width and min-width can help sometimes too.

Figured it out. I've removed any width on the body and header section, both body and header now take up 100% of the available width within th viewport. I've wrapped my main content in a container which has a max-width of 1220px, after this I get the expected results. Thanks for your valuable advice.
